# Access denied php curl in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP application that uses curl to access an external url and analyze the content of the page. My code worked perfectly on localhost but when I put it to run on the server displays the error:

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access "http://www.example.com" on this
>   server. Reference #18.aec67bc8.1417892829.438558f

My code

```
$cookie_file = '';
$post_fields = 'id=1';
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);    

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any idea?

Comment: it would be helpful to know which site is blocking you. Basically that site has rejected your HTTP request, could be the IP or the fake user agent (which can't come from EC2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2's IP ranges are frequently blocked from crawling some sites, including by StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem did some testing and other URL works, is there any way to change or hide my IP for the target server does not block me?

Comment: @LucianoMarqueto If you have a legitimate use case, contact the site and request an exemption.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. You probably need to open port 80 on your AWS instance. You can do that by editing the Security Group associated with the instance created by Elastic Beanstalk.